# How can I fix"Cannot run the macro" error?

Tags: excel, vba

When I use the "Application.OnKey" with my tetr object I got the error, but when I test with a simple sum function all works fine. If needed, I can provide a code of the class.

> Error: Cannot run the macro "C:\Path\File.xlsm'!'MoveDown tetr". The
>   macro may not be available in this workbook

```vb
Sub Game()
    Dim tetr As New tetromino
    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", "'MoveDown tetr'"
End Sub

Sub MoveDown(tetr As tetromino)
    tetr.PosY = tetr.PosY - 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", "'MoveDown ""tetr""'"`

Comment: Somehow, I start to getting ByRef argument type mismatch error ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Code still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a procedure that takes a parameter from the UI. Such macros can't be assigned to a Ribbon control and can't be assigned to a keyboard shortcut.

The keyboard shortcut needs to be "remapped" to call a procedure such as that in turn instantiates the class tetromino and calls MoveDown. Or change MoveDown and create a new procedure that does what MoveDown is currently doing.

Example:

```
Sub Game()
    Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", "'MoveDown'"
End Sub

Sub MoveDown()
    Dim tetr As New tetromino
    ExecuteMoveDown tetr
End Sub

Sub ExecuteMoveDown(tetr As tetromino)
    tetr.PosY = tetr.PosY - 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, GetAsyncKeyState was the solution.